# vmblock on archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, vmware

I have intalled the open-vm-tools-modules package but the vmblock module is unavailable. I need the vmblock to make the copy and paste between the guest and host to work.

Does anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the official vmware tools and it worked!